# can I launch one-jar using java web start

Tags: java, jar, jnlp, executable-jar, java-web-start

I am trying to lunch one-jar using web start and I am getting error -

```
Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot cannot be cast to java.applet.Applet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

JNLP contains --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Applet Takes Params</title>
        <vendor>Protype example</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.5+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="Application.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="Application"
         main-class="com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot"
         width="800"
         height="50">
             <param name="userName" value="Ashish"/>
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

I am trying to launch a **Application.jar** directly and **com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot** is the main class specify for JAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `applet-desc` tag, your Boot class must extend `Applet` (or `JApplet`). Based on the stack trace, it would appear that that class does not extend either of those.

If it's not an applet, use `application-desc` instead of `applet-desc`

Comment: Please 1) Roll-back the edit on your question.  2) Mark Chris' answer 'correct'. 3) Ask a new question about the `AccessControlException`.